# Creating release pipeline to synchronize production repo

Tags: azure-devops

I have a development repository that when new changes are pushed to it a release pipeline should get executed. The pipeline should take the changes made in that repo and synchronize it in the production repository. All repositories are located in Azure DevOps. What is the simplest way to achieve something like this?

Comment: Use branches. That's what they're for.

Comment: @DanielMann I agree, but that doesn't the problem at hand of how to synchronize two different repositories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Creating release pipeline to synchronize production repo

There is no out of way to achieve this at this moment.

To resolve this, we need to create a pipeline for the  `production` repository to invoke the git command line to clone the `development` repository, then push to the `production` repository:

```
Write-Host Starting the synchronization process
mkdir copyrepo
$sourceURL = "https://$(AZUREPO1PAT)@$(AZUREPO1)"
$destURL = "https://$(AZUREPO2PAT)@$(AZUREPO2)"
Set-Location "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/copyrepo"
git clone --mirror $sourceURL
Set-Location "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/copyrepo/"
Write-Host "*****Git removing remote origin****"
git remote rm origin
Write-Output "*****Git remote add****"
git remote add --mirror=fetch origin $destURL
Write-Output "*****Git fetch origin****"
git fetch $sourceURL
Write-Output "*****Git push to Azure Repos****"
git push origin --all -f
```

And we could also enable the CI for this pipeline. In this case, once there is any change submit to the `development` repository, it will trigger the pipeline to sync to the `production` repository.

You could check the [this thread](https://faun.pub/how-to-synchronize-azure-repos-with-external-git-repos-70ff92e51c63) for some more details.